# Intel NUC6i3 Skylake with Windows 10 - Intel HD 520 Audio over HDMI Fails

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, intel-graphics, display-driver

I recently got my Intel NUC6i3SYH. I already tested some other NUC like PCs and the NUC5i3RYH without any issues.

The system runs fine except one bug which somehow is connected to the Intel HD 520 Graphics and Intel Audio Drivers.

While working under windows there is no problem and sound works fine. The bug happens when I use Kodi or run some games (in low settings) in fullscreen. As soon as resolution or refresh rate is changed (switch to fullscreen or playing 24p videos in Kodi) the sound stops/breaks. No error is thrown in Windows.

After closing Kodi / Game / Software the sound starts working fine again. Games also work just fine in Windowed mode.

I already tested multiple Intel Driver versions (all 15.40; version 4300, 4332 and 4352), updated Bios to latest version (0028) and tested different (fresh) windows 10 installations / versions. Nothing helped so far.

Edit:
I installed newer BIOS (0033) without any changes.
Tested an DisplayPort to HDMI Adapter. Made no difference at all.
Right now I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 Server on the Skylake NUC (without any sound).

Does anyone have any ideas? It really is frustating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new beta drivers 4380 fix those problems.